# Why Doesn't My MIPS Bubble Sort Code Work?

Tags: mips, bubble-sort

This is my code:

```
.data
test1:
    .word   9
    .word   8
    .word   7
    .word   6
    .word   5
    .word   4
    .word   3

size:   .word   7

#$t0 stores i
#$t1 stores j
#$t2 stores address of array[j]
#$t3 stores address of array[j + 1]
#$t4 stores value of array[j]
#$t5 stores value of array[j + 1]
#$t6 stores 0 if array[j] >= array[j + 1], 1 otherwise

.text
bubblesort:
    addi $t0, $zero, -1     #int i = -1;
    addi $t9, $zero, 7
    la $a0, test1               #$a0 = base address of array
Loop1:
    addi $t9, $t9, -1           #$t9 = n - 1
    addi $t0, $t0, 1            #i=0
    beq $t0, $t9, print         #i < n - 1
    addi $t1, $zero, 0          #int j = 0;
    j Loop2
Loop2:
    sub $t8, $t9, $t0           #$t8 = n - i
    beq $t1, $t8, Loop1         #j < n - i - 1
    sll $t2, $t1, 2             #$t2 = j * 4
    add $t2, $t2, $a0           #t2 = $t2 + baseAddress
    lw $t4, 0($t2)              #$t4 = arr[j]
    addi $t3, $t2, 4        #$t3 = $t2 + 4
    lw $t5, 0($t3)          #$t5 = arr[j + 1]
    slt $t6, $t4, $t5       #$t6 = arr[j] < arr[j + 1]
    bne $t6, $zero, Back2       #if($t6 == 1) jump to Back2
    sw $t5, 0($t2)          #arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
    sw $t4, 0($t3)          #arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
    j Back2                 #Jump to Back2
Back2:
    addi $t1, $t1, 1        #j++
    j Loop2             #Jump to top of Loop2
exit:
    addi $v0, $zero, 10
    syscall
print:
    lw $t3, size
    la $t1, test1
    li $t2, 0
    jal print_loop

print_loop:
    beq $t2, $t3, exit
    lw $a0, 0($t1)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    j print_loop
```

And it outputs this:
6574839
It should output 3456789, I believe it is not working here

```
sw $t5, 0($t2)          #arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
sw $t4, 0($t3)          #arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
```

but I am not sure why it isn't storing the values correctly.
This is only supposed to use the instructions add, addi, addiu, addu, and, andi, la, lui, lw, nor, xor, xori, or, ori, slt, slti, sltiu, sltu, sll, srl, sra, sllv, srlv, srav, sw,
sub, subu, beq, bne, j, jal, jr.

Comment: Use the simulator's ability to set breakpoints and single-step through your code in order to find where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Keep on mind that , an integer takes 4 bytes , not only one.The size of array is 7*4 bytes.

```
    .data
    test1:
    .word   9
    .word   8
    .word   7
    .word   6
    .word   5
    .word   4
    .word   3

    size:   .word   7

    #$t0 stores i
    #$t1 stores j
    #$t2 stores address of array[j]
    #$t3 stores address of array[j + 1]
    #$t4 stores value of array[j]
    #$t5 stores value of array[j + 1]
    #$t6 stores 0 if array[j] >= array[j + 1], 1 otherwise

    .text
    bubblesort:
    #addi $t0, $zero, -1     #int i = -1;
    addi $t0,$t0,-4           # int takes 4 bytes (no 1 byte)
    #addi $t9, $zero, 7
    li $t9,28                 # size of array = 7*4 bytes 
    la $a0, test1               #$a0 = base address of array
    Loop1:

    #addi $t9, $t9, -1           #$t9 = n - 1
    addi $t9,$t9,-4              # $t9=n-1 
    addi $t0, $t0, 4            #i=0
    blt $t0, $t9, print         #i < n - 1
    addi $t1, $zero, 0          #int j = 0;
    j Loop2
    Loop2:
    sub $t8, $t9, $t0           #$t8 = n - i
    blt $t1, $t8, Loop1         #j < n - i - 1
    sll $t2, $t1, 2             #$t2 = j * 4
    add $t2, $t2, $a0           #t2 = $t2 + baseAddress
    lw $t4, 0($t2)              #$t4 = arr[j]
    addi $t3, $t2, 4        #$t3 = $t2 + 4
    lw $t5, 0($t3)          #$t5 = arr[j + 1]
    slt $t6, $t4, $t5       #$t6 = arr[j] < arr[j + 1]
    bne $t6, $zero, Back2       #if($t6 == 1) jump to Back2
    sw $t5, 0($t2)          #arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
    sw $t4, 0($t3)          #arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
    j Back2                 #Jump to Back2
    Back2:
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        #j++
    j Loop2             #Jump to top of Loop2
    exit:
    addi $v0, $zero, 10
    syscall
    print:
    lw $t3, size
    la $t1, test1
    li $t2, 0
    jal print_loop

    print_loop:
    beq $t2, $t3, exit
    lw $a0, 0($t1)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    j print_loop
```